# How to list contents of Win32 namespaces?

Tags: windows, winapi, path, namespaces, nt-native-api

Is there a way to list the contents of the `Win32 Device Namespaces` (UNC path prefix: `\\.\`) and the `Win32 File Namespaces` (UNC path prefix: `\\?\`)?

The goal would be to have an application suitable as a *command line*<sup>(1)</sup> tool that can navigate them with UNC (universal naming convention). Are there tools already written for this? I'm aware of WinObj but that is not open source and a GUI tool.

Similarly, how to list what namespaces are available under the `NT namespace`?

<del>Are there windows API calls that deal with these?</del> **Update 2** WinApi is not suitable for this, [NT Native API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Native_API) is, as pointed out in the comments by 
[Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/) and [Roger Lipscombe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8446/).

**Update 1** If they are not exposed by the winapi, how does [WinObj](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896657.aspx) list them?

Reference:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247%28VS.85%29.aspx#paths

---

(1): Win32 Console

Comment: It is a native operating system implementation detail and not exposed through the winapi.  You can explore it with SysInternals' WinObj, at least useful to see there's little of interest there.

Comment: WinObj probably uses undocumented NT API calls. The NT API is *not* the Win32 API.

Comment: @n611x007 [ObjectManagerBrowser](https://bitbucket.org/zodiacon/objectmanagerbrowser), [WinObjEx64](https://github.com/hfiref0x/WinObjEx64/) (also uses a KMD) and [ntobjx](https://bitbucket.org/assarbad/ntobjx) are three open source solutions that show nicely how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments, you can look at [WinObjEx64](https://github.com/hfiref0x/WinObjEx64) code for example. Just look at [ListObjectDirectoryTree](https://github.com/hfiref0x/WinObjEx64/blob/0d43b13f642873115160f29e58145fb54e97a6fc/Source/WinObjEx64/list.c#L360) code there.

[NtOpenDirectoryObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/devnotes/ntopendirectoryobject), [NtQueryDirectoryObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/devnotes/ntquerydirectoryobject), [NtOpenSymbolicLinkObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/devnotes/ntopensymboliclinkobject) and [NtQuerySymbolicLinkObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/devnotes/ntquerysymboliclinkobject) are the main API's that will help to enum NT objects.

Also, this old article describes how to use Object Manager Interface APIs:
https://www.drdobbs.com/using-nts-undocumented-object-manager-in/184416468